# Xamarin App builds and runs on simulator, but on real phone I get Assembly Failure

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin based mobile app. It has previously deployed to an iPhone, and is currently working on the simulator. However, when I try to Debug on my iPhone, I get:

> Error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'PCLStorage.Abstractions, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=286fe515a2c35b64' (MT2002) (My_App.iOS)

PCLStorage is installed and up to date in my iOS and Core projects, although neither have any references to the package. It was installed when I added the AWS Core SDK. How do I resolve this error, I assume that is what is stopping the debug on iPhone?

## Edit: (based on Answer below)

If I disable the linker in my build settings, I get the error:

> My_App/iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly 'My_App/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone4.1-9.2.1/mtouch-cache/Build/AWSSDK.Core.dll' (MT3001) (My_App.iOS)

I would really appreciate some suggestions as I haven't made much headroom with this...

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling "Linker" in the build options for Device builds.  It's possible that if you are not directly referencing the library, the linker is stripping it out, causing it to fail at runtime.

Comment: If I do that, I get this error: >/My_App/iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly 'My_App/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone4.1-9.2.1/mtouch-cache/Build/AWSSDK.Core.dll' (MT3001)

Comment: Do the new details help? I am really not having much luck with this.

Comment: You need to turn on verbose messages to see what is causing the issue - http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40406/could-not-aot-the-assembly

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now and report back!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem after switching from the simulator to an actual device
Fortunately, I've gotten the error only in 3 pages...
Fix was to remove the assembly attribute from the XAML:
From
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:XXX.ViewModels;assembly=XXX" 
To
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:XXX.ViewModels"